# URL Says "404 Not Found", Yet File Downloads

Tags: php, image, download, windows-server

I built a web application for a client and then transferred it over to his server. It didn't work, so I had to call the server company and have them fix it. It was nice of them, but now I have to change all my web roots around. While doing it, I found a weird bug when it comes to URLs that go to files. Instead of being able to view the files (like an image) I get a 404 Error: "Page cannot be displayed, The requested URL was not found on this server." Yet, at the same time, the image downloads. I have never seen this before in my life. I don't want to automatically download an image: I just want to view it.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, and how I can prevent it.

An example URL is http://holyfamilyregina.com/CMS/downloads/images/cwl.png

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that you are *not* actually getting a 404 error on that URL, but rather, that you're visiting that URL in a window/tab that already had a 404 page open. Usually, when your browser decides to download a URL's content rather than display it, it will leave the previous page (even if it's a 404) intact. (That doesn't actually solve your problem, but it might help address your confusion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the headers that I get from the image in your post:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Sun, 07 Apr 2023 04:18:16 GMT
Server: IceWarp/10.4.4
Date: Sun, 07 Apr 2013 04:18:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 9797
Last-Modified: Sun, 07 Apr 2013 03:47:12 GMT
```

No 404, but the file's content type is set to `octet-stream` (a stream of 8 bits), which is used when you want someone to download a file.

You need to tell your server company to configure the server so that it serves images with their proper `Content-Type` headers.

Comment: It's not my server company, it's one my client wanted to go with. They've been a major pain for about the past month. I'll tell them what you said, and a few more colourful things too. Thanks a lot. I'm sure this is the problem.